# Passing value of version in ThisBuild setting defined in version.sbt to artifactName?

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-release

I use sbt **0.13** and the [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin in order to automatically increment version of a Play application, so I have file `version.sbt` with the following line:

```
version in ThisBuild := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

I also prepare mapping artifact name in order to prepare package with specific name per environment:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, dependencies = appDependencies).
      settings(
        ...
        artifactName := {(sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) => {
          val suffix = "-" + sys.props.getOrElse("environment","dev") + (if (artifact.classifier.isDefined) "-" + artifact.classifier.get else "")
          artifact.name + "_" + sv.binary + "-" + version + suffix + "." + artifact.extension
        }},
        ...
      )
```

Evaluation of above code result in version value equal to 1.0 (probably it is some kind of default) because version.sbt define value as 1.0-SNAPSHOT 
In lot cases I do something like this in order to use version from `ThisBuild`:

```
SomeTask <<= (version in ThisBuild) map { ver => ...
  some ver usage
  ...
}
```

But this specific solution does not work. Can someone provide an example how to use this specific value in `artifactName` setting?

Another solution that will help me is to get string value from this variable. Thanks to it I will be able to do next thing:

```
val appVersion := ... // some operation on version in ThisBuild
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, dependencies = appDependencies)
```

I want to pass the value of the `version` setting from `version.sbt` file to `artifactName` in order to provide the name for produced package.

Comment: For the last part of your question, I guess, you want just `(version in ThisBuild).value` (if you are using sbt 0.13)

Comment: What sbt version do you use? I've changed the title of your question, but I'm not sure it really reflects what you're working on. It's unclear from the description. It'd be worthwhile to post a sbt command/task you want to execute and the expected outcome. That'd help a lot to me.

Comment: @laughedelic I use sbt 0.13, exactly I want to use somethnig like (version in ThisBuild).value but it can be only used in Tasks

Comment: @JacekLaskowski what i was trying to do is just to run:
sbt -Denvironment=dev "release with-defaults" - as a result I expect to have published tar file project_name-version_from_file-dev.tar in artifactory, created tag in mercurial as well as bumped version of the project. All mentioned steps I already configured but I have problem with passing version value to the artifactName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with sbt **0.13.3-SNAPSHOT**:

```
[sbt-0-13-3]> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.3-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.3/}sbt-0-13-3 1.0-build_sbt
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.0-RC3
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyModule, sbt.plugins.JvmModule, sbt.plugins.GlobalModule, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, sbtman.Plugin, np.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

**tl;dr** Use `(version in ThisBuild).value` when you need the value of the `version` setting in `ThisBuild` configuration.

Given the following **version.sbt** file:

```
version in ThisBuild := "1.0-version_sbt"
```

and the following **build.sbt** (note `(version in ThisBuild).value`):

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0-RC3"

version := "1.0-build_sbt"

artifactName := {
  (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) => {
    val suffix = "-" + sys.props.getOrElse("environment","dev") + (if (artifact.classifier.isDefined) "-" + artifact.classifier.get else "")
    artifact.name + "_" + sv.binary + "-" + (version in ThisBuild).value + suffix + "." + artifact.extension
  }
}
```

sbt shell gave me the following output:

```
[sbt-0-13-3]> show makePom::artifactPath
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.3/target/scala-2.11.0-RC3/sbt-0-13-3_2.11.0-RC3-1.0-version_sbt-dev.pom
```

I used `makePom::artifactPath` settings as I've noticed it's a reverse dependency of `artifactName` (I wouldn't otherwise have been able to display the value of the `artifactName` function):

```
[sbt-0-13-3]> inspect artifactName
[info] Setting: scala.Function3[sbt.ScalaVersion, sbt.ModuleID, sbt.Artifact, java.lang.String] = <function3>
[info] Description:
[info]  Function that produces the artifact name from its definition.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.3/}sbt-0-13-3/*:artifactName
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.3/build.sbt:5
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  {.}/*:version
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:makePom::artifactPath
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:artifactName
[info]  {.}/*:artifactName
[info]  */*:artifactName
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:artifactName
```

As to the case where you want to set the version of a Play project to `version in ThisBuild` you don't have to worry about it as sbt does this for you.

```
val appVersion := ... // some operation on version in ThisBuild
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, dependencies = appDependencies)
```

What `play.Project` does (see [play.Project.scala on GitHub](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/Project.scala#L59)) is to pass `applicationVersion` to `version` and since you set the version in `version.sbt` it's already set by sbt itself. If you however want to do it explicitly, do as follows:

```
version := (version in ThisBuild).value
```

in `build.sbt`.

```
[sbt-0-13-3]> show version
[info] 1.0-build_sbt
[sbt-0-13-3]> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.3/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-3 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.3/)
[sbt-0-13-3]> show version
[info] 1.0-version_sbt
```

Comment: Ok it works but there is additional problem which I successfully resolve:
when you do **not** set the version explicitly:
    `version := (version in ThisBuild).value` 
and run `sbt dist` you will receive zip package with next name: project_name-1.0.zip (at least I get such package in sbt 0.13.0 - does not use value from version.sbt

Comment: It appears that `sbt dist` (the task that comes with Play) doesn't use the scopes we work with. Could you raise another question so it's more visible in the SO community? I also suggest upgrading sbt to 0.13.1 which boils down to amending `project/build.properties`.